# $y''+6y'+c=0$ satisfies $\lim_{x\to \infty} y(x)= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Diffrential equation $$y''+ 6y' +c =0$$ satisfies $$\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x)= 0$$

then what's the range of $c$?

please help

Comment: Do you mean when $\;f(x)\;$ is the (a) solution of the di. eq., or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite

$$y''e^{6t}+6y'e^{6t}+ce^{6t}=(y'e^{6t})'+ce^{6t}=0.$$

Then integrating once,

$$y'e^{6t}+\frac c6e^{6t}+c'=0,$$

$$y'+\frac c6+c'e^{-6t}=0.$$

For $y$ to keep a finite value at infinity, you need $c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here $y''+6y=-c$ $\implies$ $y(x)= A+Be^{-6x}-\frac{c}{6}. $
Then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}$$y(x)=0$ gives $A-\frac{c}{6}=0$ $\implies$ $c=6A,$ where A is an arbitrary constant.